# How to distinguish between unspecified and specified parameters in PHP methods?

Tags: php, design-patterns, parameters

I find myself pondering this from time to time, so I thought I'd ask for some community input. Given the following PHP method:

```
/**
 * Sets and/or provides the value of a setting.
 *
 * @param string $name The name of the setting.
 * @param mixed|null $value The new setting value, null to leave unchanged.
 * @return mixed The setting value.
 */
 public function setting(string $name, $value = null) {

     if ($value !== null) {
        $this->setSettingValue($name, $value);
     }

     $return $this->getSettingValue($name);

 }
```

The value type of a "setting" can be any primitive type, including the NULL value. Setting the value of the setting "foo" (which e.g. currently has the value 42) to NULL won't work with this method. I've seen and used multiple ways to circumvent this over the years, but is there anything which is considered a best practice here?

Comment: why do you need to check against non-null to set the value? Surely either way you're setting the value (to null or whatever is passed)?

Comment: Why do you don't use name of setting param? Should not it be  `$this->setSettingValue($name, $value);` ?

Comment: '*but is there anything which is considered a best practice here?*' - Yes, be explicit and separate your getters and setters.

Comment: @splash58 You're right – I've updated the example.

Comment: @Script47 I won't disagree with that, and I know my example isn't the best one to illustrate when you'd really need to distinguish between the two situations. It could have been rephrased to focus on the missing feature of method overloading in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`func_num_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to find out how many arguments were passed to a function:

```
function test(string $name, $value = null) {
    echo func_num_args() . PHP_EOL;
}

test("x", 4);
test("y", null);
test("z");
```

Output:

```
2
2
1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lGMsF)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume the class that this `setting` method belongs to is written by you. Or else there is nothing else you can really do.

I think the clear solution is to have an extra array that marks which value is "dirty".

```php
/**
 * Sets and/or provides the value of a setting.
 *
 * @param string $name The name of the setting.
 * @param mixed|null $value The new setting value, null to leave unchanged.
 * @return mixed The setting value.
 */
public function setting(string $name, $value = null) {
    if ($value !== null) {
       $this->setSettingValue($value);
    }
    $this->dirty[$name] = true; // add this line to mark which settings is set
    return $this->getSettingValue($name);
}
```

Then when you need to save the setting values, you can check if the `$name` key exists in the `$this->dirty` property to see if it needs to be saved.

But after that, you'll need a new way to express that a setting has not set (instead of setting to a `null` value). For the settings that do not have a value, you'd probably need to throw an exception so it is distingulish from `null` value.

Also, you'd need a separate method to unset a setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for seperate get and set methods, but i'm assuming this is not the answer you're looking for.

What are you using the default value for anyway? in this example it looks like you are only using it to catch the case where no value has been passed. in that case i would default to a type of value that is outside the range of possible valid values.

E.G if a `bool` is not a valid value then i would  default to that `$value = false`

If all scalar types are valid options, default to an `empty array` or `stdClassobject`

But again, having a unified get/set method (yes, even a wrapper around proper get/set methods) is considered bad design